# What is the packet of stuff inside a package of ground turkey?

Tags: turkey

When I buy ground turkey from Publix, under the ground turkey in the package there is a packet of something pinkish colored than isn't mentioned on the label, what is it? Is it maybe something from the turkey used for flavoring a broth or something?

Comment: Is there anything written on the "packet of stuff", such as **Do not eat**?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please include a photo? It’s almost certainly something that belongs to the packaging, but to be sure we need more information.

Comment: I've seen those and they are placed under most meats and, *i believe* are there to absorb the liquid in the meat. If you look closely at this item is is not much more than some sort of sponge.

Answer (score 7):

Where I live most prepackaged meats come with a kind of fluids sponge or mat.

Those can be part of the packaging, can be clearly recognizable mats between the meat and the packaging, or it can be a bag shaped package which looks like it could contain something edible.

As it is something made to contain the liquids drained out of the meat and hold it, I do not think you should use it or anything coming out of it, as you can not know what they put in to hold the liquids. (Although it should be food safe as it is in contact with the meat.)

I see that @Tetsujin in a comment calls it a meat diaper, which seems to fit the bag and mat types.

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely it's an oxygen absorber.

Comment: or 'meat diaper'.